# Connecting android device over TCPIP

Tags: android, tcp, ip, adb

I am trying to connect my android device over tcpip and here is my experience so far:

```
$ ./adb tcpip
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
restarting in TCP mode port: 67

$ ./adb connect 192.168.1.250:67
unable to connect to 192.168.1.250:67:67

$ ./adb connect 192.168.1.250
unable to connect to 192.168.1.250:5555
```

Then I did:

```
$ ./adb kill-server
```

And then:

```
$ ./adb tcpip 5555
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ ./adb connect 192.168.1.250
connected to 192.168.1.250:5555
```

1. Why was I able to connect only after doing `./adb tcpip 5555` and ?
2. Why was I not able to connect by doing `./adb connect 192.168.1.250:67`
3. What do these messages at the o/p of `./adb tcpip` mean?

   - daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
   - daemon started successfully *

     restarting in TCP mode port: 67

`adb kill-server` is not needed. I can do:

`adb tcpip 5555` which gives: restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

What does the above message mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a page I just read the server can only start in the ports numbered 5555 to 5585.

"One thing to remember is that you can only choose a port number within the range of [5555...5585] (the reason being that ADB Server only works with these ports). So for instance you could do:

`adb tcpip 5555`" (via http://www.chentir.com/?p=1613)